# How do I Raise an Event using Rhino Mocks that has a ref bool parameter

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am trying to write a test that covers my error handling in a particular class.  This class is listening for an Error event with the following signature:

```
OnError(int ErrorNumber, string ErrorText, ref bool retry)
```

The problem is with the ref bool variable at the end.  I am using Rhino Mocks to create a mock interface for testing and when I try to raise the error using the following:

```
bool retry = false;
AdapterMock.Raise(x => x.Error += null, 0, "0", ref retry);
```

It won't even compile, telling me it can't convert from ref bool to Object.

If I change the signature to:

```
bool retry = false;
AdapterMock.Raise(x => x.Error += null, 0, "0", retry);
```

I compiles fine but the test fails with System.InvalidOperationException : Parameter #3 is System.Boolean but should be System.Boolean&

I'm pulling my hair out on this one, how do I properly raise this event in my mock?

Comment: Any possibility of re-writing the OnError delegate to the .NET-standards for arguments -- i.e. (object sender, OnErrorEventArgs args)?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
AdapterMock.Raise( x=> x.Error += null, Arg<int>.Is.Equal(0), Arg<string>.Is.Equal("0"), Arg.Ref(ref Is.Equal(retry)));
```